# Elasticsearch DateTime Range Query

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 5.1 and I am trying to query a date time mapping that looks like this

```
"startTime": {
        "properties": {
          "date": {
            "properties": {
              "day": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "month": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "year": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "time": {
            "properties": {
              "hour": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "minute": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "nano": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "second": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Tried doing this query:

```
{
  "query": {
     "range": {
      "startTime.date": {
        "lte": "2017-05-08",
        "gte": "2017-06-05"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

also tried

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "startTime": {
        "lte": "now+2w/w",
        "gte": "now-2w/w",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "startTime": {
        "lte": "now+2w/w",
        "gte": "now-2w/w"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I would query for a time range 2 weeks in the past and 2 weeks in the future?  All the variations I have tried are not yielding results even though I know there should be some results.

Comment: Why don't you simply have a normal `date` field instead of separating all the date/hour components into single fields?

Comment: you data for startdate type doesn't represent a valid date object for elastic

Comment: That is the mapping in my elasticsearch cluster, I did a GetMapping to present how my date time is stored.  As such it is a valid date type.